# cffi installation

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl, asdf

I'm trying to install cffi package into sbcl. 
First, I tried clbuild that is recommended on the cffi installation page. 
When I tried to run :

```
clbuild quickload cffi
```

I was given an error saying :

```
The function ASDF::SOURCE-REGISTRY is undefined.
```

I then tried asdf-install, it end up complaining about

```
Component "cffi-examples" not found
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

For asdf-install, I'm running sbcl with slime. It seems that whenever it complains about a component that is missing, that component is actually installed. I just have to abort the debugger and restart Emacs, start slime, and do that install again, and it will finish successfully. If I don't run it with slime, just running it inside sbcl prompt in terminal, it will keep complaining about the component missing nonstop.

So to get cffi installed with asdf-install, I had to restart Emacs for about 4-5 times.

I'm not sure if there is configuration issue with sbcl?

I suppose I should ask this question in different thread.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's pretty easy with Quicklisp. To install Quicklisp:

- Download http://beta.quicklisp.org/quicklisp.lisp
- sbcl --load quicklisp.lisp
- (quicklisp-quickstart:install)
- (ql:add-to-init-file)

Then you can install and load CFFI like so:

- (ql:quickload "cffi")

I wrote a bit about how I manage small projects and their required libraries at [Making a small Lisp project with quickproject and Quicklisp](http://xach.livejournal.com/278047.html).

Answer (score 3):

Here are the exact steps for manual installation under Windows 7:

First, download and install SBCL from:

http://www.sbcl.org/platform-table.html

Then download and untar (`tar xzf ...`) [babel](http://common-lisp.net/project/babel/releases/babel_latest.tar.gz), [alexandria](http://common-lisp.net/~loliveira/tarballs/inofficial/alexandria-2008-07-29.tar.gz), [trivial-features](http://common-lisp.net/~loliveira/tarballs/trivial-features/trivial-features_latest.tar.gz), and [cffi](http://common-lisp.net/project/cffi/releases/cffi_latest.tar.gz).

Then, start SBCL, load ASDF, and add the paths to these systems to `asdf:*central-registry*`:

```
C:\Program Files\Steel Bank Common Lisp\1.0.49>sbcl.exe --core sbcl.core
This is SBCL 1.0.49, an implementation of ANSI Common Lisp.
More information about SBCL is available at <http://www.sbcl.org/>.

SBCL is free software, provided as is, with absolutely no warranty.
It is mostly in the public domain; some portions are provided under
BSD-style licenses.  See the CREDITS and COPYING files in the
distribution for more information.

This is experimental prerelease support for the Windows platform: use
at your own risk.  "Your Kitten of Death awaits!"
* (load "asdf/asdf")

T
* (push "C:/Users/dhl/build/asdf/babel_0.3.0/" asdf:*central-registry*)

("C:/Users/dhl/build/asdf/babel_0.3.0/")
* (push "C:/Users/dhl/build/asdf/alexandria/" asdf:*central-registry*)

("C:/Users/dhl/build/asdf/alexandria/" "C:/Users/dhl/build/asdf/babel_0.3.0/")
* (push "C:/Users/dhl/build/asdf/trivial-features_0.6/" asdf:*central-registry*)

("C:/Users/dhl/build/asdf/trivial-features_0.6/"
 "C:/Users/dhl/build/asdf/alexandria/" "C:/Users/dhl/build/asdf/babel_0.3.0/")
* (push "C:/Users/dhl/build/asdf/cffi_0.10.6/" asdf:*central-registry*)

("C:/Users/dhl/build/asdf/cffi_0.10.6/"
 "C:/Users/dhl/build/asdf/trivial-features_0.6/"
 "C:/Users/dhl/build/asdf/alexandria/" "C:/Users/dhl/build/asdf/babel_0.3.0/")
*
```

(Of course, you'd have to give your paths to the libraries instead of `"C:/Users/dhl/...")

Then, you can load CFFI:

```
* (asdf:load-system 'cffi)
[much compilation output]
T
*
```

Now, that's pretty much the bare bones way to install systems for Common Lisp. Nowadays, there is [Quicklisp](http://www.quicklisp.org/), which is easy to use and covered by Xach's answer. Also, note that there are better ways to register your systems with asdf, like symlinking the asd-files to a single directory on platforms that support symlinking, and ASDF 2 provides a `source-registry` facility, so you won't have to deal with `asdf:*central-registry*` at all (I still like it for REPL use).

All in all, I guess Xach's answer provides the easiest way to get a working installation of CFFI, so I recommend his answer and will vote it up, but I already started writing my article before he posted it, and maybe its of some use to you to know how to do things manually.

Comment: Thank you very much this. I was going to try the manual installation at first, but I hesitated since I'm still not quite familiar with CL system in general, like how to load library, or where does it look for installed library, etc. I think your explanation really helps.

Comment: Did you mean "source-registry"? In .sbclrc, I use *central-registry*. What's the difference between *central-registry* and source-registry?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the correction (fixed). The difference is, in a nutshell, that you can put system directories under `~/.local/share/common-lisp/source/`, and everything should just work. See http://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf.html#Configuring-ASDF for a quick introduction, and http://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf.html#Controlling-where-ASDF-searches-for-systems for details. The `asdf:*central-registry*`, in contrast, is a list of directories in which ASDF looks for asd-files (without descending into subdirs). Usually, one would have one directory and symlink all asd-files to it.